# file paths to json tree structure

Tags: javascript

I have data as following: 
`

```
[
  {path: "path1/path2/path3/index.file", title: "path3 Title"},
  {path: "path1/path2/index.file", title: "path2 Title"},
  {path: "path1/path2/path3/path4.file", title: "path4 Title"},
  {path: "path5/path5.file", title: "path5 Title"},
  {path: "path1/index.file", title: "path1 Title"},
  {path: "index.file", title: "path0 Title"},
]
```

`
and i need something like :-

`

```
[
  {title: "path1 title", children: [
    {title: "path2 Title", children: [
      title: "path3 Title", children: [
        title: "path 4 Title", children: []
      ]
    ]
  ]},
  {
    title: "path 5 title", children: []
  },
  {
    title: "path 0 title", children: []
  }
]
```

`

so far i have written this but its not helping me at all.
`

```
let treepath = {};
      paths.forEach(path => {
        let levels = path.split("/");
        let file = levels.pop();

        let prevLevel = treePath;
        let prevProp = levels.shift();

        levels.forEach(prop => {
          prevLevel[prevProp] = prevLevel[prevProp] || {};
          prevLevel = prevLevel[prevProp];
          prevProp = prop;
        });

        prevLevel[prevProp] = (prevLevel[prevProp] || []).concat([file]);
      });

    console.log('treepath', treePath);
```

`

There can be various paths. they are coming dynamically. i need to set them as children. i need to do this in Javascript code.Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Why is `"path4 Title"` nested inside `"path3 Title"` when both of them are at the same level? I think you are missing a `/path4/` subpath from here: `path1/path2/path3/path4.file`

Comment: A lot of things don't make sense here. Where does the `"path1 title"` in the output coming from? It's not present in the input. Are we supposed to ignore the `title` property altogether? You are not using `title` in your code anywhere. Please create an example with some actual data. When you add foo-bar-baz, it ends up looking like this

Comment: path4 is not missing. path4.file can directly be there. i have to work on titles in the files. and i forgot about the path1 title url. i edited it to make it more sense now. title is the main key here that will be used further

Comment: Why are `"path1/path2/path3/index.file"` and `"path1/path2/path3/path4.file"` not at the same level? Only difference between is the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a shadow tree and assign the title later to the the structure.

```js
var data = [{ path: "path1/path2/path3/index.file", title: "path3 Title" }, { path: "path1/path2/index.file", title: "path2 Title" }, { path: "path1/path2/path3/path4.file", title: "path4 Title" }, { path: "path5/path5.file", title: "path5 Title" }, { path: "path1/index.file", title: "path1 Title" }, { path: "index.file", title: "path0 Title" }],
    tree = data
        .reduce((r, { path, title }) => {
            let directories = ('root/' + path).split('/');

            directories.pop();

            directories
                .reduce((d, key) => {
                    if (!d[key]) {
                        d[key] = { _: [] };
                        d._.push(d[key].parent = { title: null, children: d[key]._ });
                    }
                    return d[key];
                }, r)
                .parent
                .title = title;
            return r;
        }, { _: [] })
        ._;

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. but instead of getting the file names i want title to be actual title that is given in the files. thankyou

Comment: just add this parts and replace `title` with your values.

Comment: Your answer does not get me the answer. However your previous edited answer was correct except for the title part. I am still not able to figure out how to get title.