# How should I structure a data tree in javascript so that it can be parsed by the front-end?

Tags: javascript, json, tree, maps, javascript-objects

I have a `tree` data structure where every node is an `object` and I want to send the entire tree to the front-end. JavaScript doesn't allow objects as keys so I can't implement the solution below

```
tree= {{}:{{}:{}, {}:{}, ...}, ...}
```

How do I achieve this and how do I parse back the tree in the front-end .

Comment: javascript does allow objects as keys in a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), but it is unclear why that is necessary or how you are *'sending it to the frontend'*.

Comment: `{"{}":{"{}":{}, "{}":{}, ...}, ...}`?

Comment: @JaromandaX It is a pseudo code. The keys are parent nodes and values are child nodes. The objects are not empty.

Comment: @pilchard If I JSON.stringify the maps and send it . Is it possible to convert it back to maps ? My concern is that stringified keys won't get converted back to maps.

Comment: no, and you would lose the referential keys of the Map anyway. As I said in my first comment, I'm unsure why you think you need objects as keys, there are plenty of ways of representing a tree structure that can be safely converted to JSON

Comment: @pilchard I am open to new ways? Can you tell me how can I do it .

Comment: see: [How to create a tree structure representation in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063481/how-to-create-a-tree-structure-representation-in-json) or [file paths to json tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62089566/file-paths-to-json-tree-structure), etc. etc. Also see: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

To make your data serializable (e.g. as JSON), you should use a different data structure where you don't use objects as Map-keys. Check if you have a unique identifier for each object (maybe an ID property?). If not, create one for each object (use a sequential number). Then encode your tree with these identifiers as object keys. Now you can serialize/deserialize using JSON.